# Different shapes/dimensions of shapley values using explainer(X) or explainer.shap_values(X)

Tags: python, shap

Why results this in different shapes/dimensions? (And therefore also in different summary_plots)

```
# Using the shap_values method 
# summary plot shows "bar"-plot of mean(|SHAP values|)
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(LGBMClassifier)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X)
np.shape(shap_values)
>>> (2, 3888, 259)
```

```
# Using the call method instead 
# summary plot shows "beeswarm"-plot
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(LGBMClassifier)
shap_values = explainer(X)
np.shape(shap_values)
>>> (3888, 259, 2)
```

For `shap_version == 0.39.0`

Answer (score 1):

stolen from https://github.com/slundberg/shap/issues/2116#issuecomment-896459949:

explainer(X) returns shap._explanation.Explanation and explainer.shap_values(X) returns numpy.ndarray.
The numpy.ndarray is just the shap values, but the shap._explanation.Explanation contains not only the shap values, but also the base values and feature values.